# R - Loop to scrap and combine pages using rvest

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, dplyr, rvest

I would like to scrape data contained in tables across multiple pages. I used the code below to scrape the first table, but I am not sure how to scrape the tables in other pages:

```
library (rvest)
library(dplyr)
    
WA_link<-"https://www.worldathletics.org/records/toplists/sprints/100-metres/outdoor/women/senior/2021?page=1"
WA_page<-read_html(WA_link)
    
WA_table<-WA_page  %>% html_nodes("table.records-table") %>%
      html_table() %>% . [[1]]
```

I would like all tables (or a given number of tables) to be scraped and then be combined into one data frame. How can my code here be adapted to achieve this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a loop to scrape and combine pages 1-4. I am not sure how to scrape the website to see how many pages are in the set, so for now the number of pages should be changed manually.

```
pages <- 1:4 # where 4==whatever the number of pages is..

WA_list=list()
for(i in seq_along(pages)){
  WA_link<-paste0("https://www.worldathletics.org/records/toplists/sprints/100-metres/outdoor/women/senior/2021?page=",pages[i])
  WA_page<-read_html(WA_link)

  WA_list[[i]] <- WA_page  %>% html_nodes("table.records-table") %>%
    html_table() %>% . [[1]]

}
WA_table <- dplyr::bind_rows(WA_list)
```

Alternatively, you can scan many more than expected.

```
pages <- c(1:100)

WA_list=vector("list", length(pages))
  ## "pre-allocate" an empty list of length 5
for(i in seq_along(pages)){
  print(i)
  WA_link<-paste0("https://www.worldathletics.org/records/toplists/sprints/100-metres/outdoor/women/senior/2021?page=",pages[i])
  WA_page<-read_html(WA_link)

  WA_list[[i]] <- WA_page  %>% html_nodes("table.records-table") %>%
    html_table() %>% . [[1]]
  WA_table <- dplyr::bind_rows(WA_list) # this is a crude solution to creating a data frame while allowing the loop to stop when the max page has been reached. ideally, there would be a logical here for when no data is retrieved on pages[i]
}
```

Note: Hopefully someone can edit this answer to exit the loop at i where no data exists in `WA_page  %>% html_nodes("table.records-table") %>% html_table() %>% . [[1]]`. This solution would then move the `bind_rows()` to after the loop to prevent redundant processes.

Comment: Thank you so much Jessica. To know how many pages to import without typing would be perfect but it works very well this way.

Comment: You could increase the size of pages to something much higher than expected. E.g., your example page has 37 pages. You could scan up to 100 pages. If the page has no data, nothing will load in. It will just take a bit longer to process. I've updated my answer to include this possible solution.